# npm installed pre-push hook linked to a custom script is always skipped

Tags: git, npm, hook, package.json

I wanted to stop all developers from being able to do a git push to master (--force excluded). Instead of asking everyone to create a pre-push file in .git/hooks folder, I wanted to automate the process using npm and add the required files to the remote git repository.

I added to the "pre-push" in package.json which points to a custom script,

```
"pre-push": {
  "run": [
    "prepushscript"
  ]
},

"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "test": "node_modules/.bin/gulp test",
  "prepushscript": "prepushscript"
},

"devDependencies": {
  .
  .
  "pre-push": "^0.1.0",
  .
  .
}
```

Note: The custom script prepushscript is at the same file level as the package.json.

The prepushscript file is fairly straight-forward

```
protected_branch='master'  
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $protected_branch = $current_branch ]  
then  
    echo "Error: You are attempting to push to a protected branch."
exit 1 # push will not execute
fi
```

The custom script works because on creating a local pre-push file in .git/hooks folder and attempting to push to protected branch results in the script’s echo error message to be seen. Npm install creates the symlink in the .git/hooks folder as well. Once I have a commit ready to push while on local master and run git push, the push goes through and I get the following,

```
pre-push:
pre-push: Failed to find the root of this git repository, cannot locate the `package.json`.
pre-push: Skipping the pre-push hook.
pre-push:
Everything up-to-date
```

I’ve tried replacing the prepushscript entry with a simple echo statement in the package.json to see if it’s a problem with the script but I get the same console log. Other attempts that were made were adding extensions to the prepushscript file to see if it runs.

The main problem that I cannot figure out is I cannot locate the source of error and what it has to do with the package.json. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with "pre-push" npm package. It seems like it doesn't my window git full path with space, like "Program Files". I had to go for "[git-pre-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-pre-push)" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It's failing on this line:

```
 this.root = this.exec(this.git, ['rev-parse', '--show-toplevel']);
```

https://github.com/dflourusso/pre-push/blob/master/index.js#L173

Which is trying to get the absolute path of the 'top-level' directory.

`this.git` contains the path to the git executable. The problem occurs when using a git GUI and it uses its own embedded executable. I ran into this problem when using SourceTree and changed my preferences so that it used the System executable:

SourceTree > Preferences > Git > Use System Git (Git Version)

If you are using a different GUI go to its preferences and make sure that it is using the System executable.